# How to raise exception if None value encountered in dict?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to raise a `KeyError` exception if the value returned is `None`, but the following throws a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` exception.

```
try:
   protocol = serverInfo_D['protocol'] or raise KeyError("protocol not present")
except KeyError:
   print "Improper server config"
```

What's a simple way to get this working?

Comment: AFAIK Python's dictionary already throws a KeyError exception if the specified key is missing.

Comment: @Simone - He's trying to raise the exception when the value is `None`, not just when the key is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're getting a `SyntaxError` because `raise` is a statement not an expression, so the `or raise KeyError` part doesn't make [syntactic] sense. One workaround is to put just that into a function like the following, which is only called if the looked-up value is something non-True, like `None`, `0`, `''`, and `[]`.

**Caveat**: Note that doing this is potentially confusing since what it effectively does is make the presence of any of those types of values appear to be as though the `protocol` key wasn't there even though technically it was...so you might want to consider deriving your own specialized exception class from one of the [built-ins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions) and then deal with those instead of (ab)using what `KeyError` [normally means](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError).

```
def raise_KeyError(msg=''): raise KeyError(msg)  # Doesn't return anything.

try:
    protocol = serverInfo_D['protocol'] or raise_KeyError('protocol not present')
except KeyError:
    print('Improper server config!')
```

Comment: is so dumb that raise is not an expression in python 3, is like they didn't learn nothing from the print fiasco

Answer (score 7):

If you want it in one line you could always make a function:

```
def valueOrRaise(data, key):
    value = data.get(key)
    if value is None:
        raise KeyError("%s not present" % key)
    return value

try:
    protocol = valueOrRaise(serverInfo_D, 'protocol')
except KeyError:
    print "server config is not proper"
```

Answer (score 2):

The `try` and `except KeyError` combination should work. What is not working for you?

And since this in continuation of your previous question, that was not working because you were using `dict.get`, which never throws up `KeyError`.

However, the code in this question will. And you don't need `or raise KeyError`.

```
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> d.get('c')  # no KeyError
>>> d['c']      # KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

Comment: what if d['c'] contains a None value?

Comment: The `or raise KeyError` part of the OP's code is a `SyntaxError` because `raise` is a statement not an expression.

Comment: Not quite what the OP asked - the value is present, so it won't raise the KeyError, but it has a None value, which the OP wants to be an exception case.

Comment: @martineua, @McGuire: If you check out the question the OP asked before this, it makes my point clear as to what I am trying to say. I answered that so I was basing this on that. I maybe wrong, but I think the OP was confusing the answer to previous question and that is what I wanted to clarify. If it wrong, let me know and I will edit/ delete it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to have an exception, if you're really using it like this? Just use `.get()` and check for `None`.

```
protocol = serverInfo_D.get('protocol')
if protocol is None:
   print "server config is not proper"
```

Comment: Because some programs need to crash if the key doesn't exist because it means something went terribly wrong and letting the program continue will just cause unpredictable behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more along the lines of what you want. Please comment if you need it to change.

```
try:
    protocol = serverInfo_D['protocol'] 
    if protocol == None:
        raise KeyError("protocol not present")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: can't we use or and put it in a single line.. coz I have lot of such validations.

Comment: I think this addresses a different problem; he assumes that if the specified protocol is not handled then serverInfo_D['protocol'] is not set, thus assigning from it throws a KeyError. Your code seems to assume that it is set to None, thus a KeyError must be thrown manually.